# Viewing SQL Files

Tags: sql, database

Just got a 488mb .sql file and i need to view the contents of it, whats the way to go about it? i've tried opening it in a few GUI programs, either they don't see the file, one of the programs asked for an encryption key although none of the others did. Im not the most savvy with SQL so a point in the right direction or a easy way to view it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 488Mb seems an odd size for a .sql file. Isn't that a backup for a SQL database? If so, you'll need to restore it, and you'll need to know what database vendor/version: Is a Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

a proper .sql file is just text, so any text editor will work.

Answer (score 0):

If its just an .sql file, simply right click it and edit with notepad.  Or notepad++ which is better for sql files